# BIOS not showing splash screen on dual monitor setup, but still takes keystrokes

Tags: windows, boot, multiple-monitors, bios, hdmi

Here are my specs:

16gb DDR4

AMD Ryzen 7 1800x

GTX 1080Ti

GTX 1080

MSI Carbon Gaming Pro x370 -- edited to fix name

2x monitors: 1x 60hz, 1x 144hz both connected via HDMI to 1080Ti

I've been working at this all day bc I need to change a setting in my BIOS, but I noticed that I was not getting the BIOS splash screen. I reset the CMOS already and later found out that the BIOS is responding to keystrokes, but it won't display the BIOS image on my desktop. If it helps, the monitor to the right is the main one in windows, but I doubt that affects this since it is a windows config. From the BIOS, I was able to press F6 -> Enter -> F10 -> Enter which triggers a save and restart of my system. That happens without fault, so I know that I am able to access the BIOS to a small extent.

After figuring that out I have tried:
Unplugging the 60hz monitor (secondary m)
Unplugging the 144hz monitor (primary m)
Unplugging the Oculus rift from the 1080Ti
Switching the 144hz monitor to a DP from an HDMI

Still no luck.  Anybody have any ideas to try?

Edit solved:
Plugged the monitors from my 1080Ti (secondary PCIe) to 1080 (primary PCIe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If something has gone wrong with the BIOS, and reset didn't help, then the next
step is flashing the latest version.

You may find the latest BIOS version on the webpage of
[Support For X370 GAMING PRO CARBON](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/support/X370-GAMING-PRO-CARBON).
Use the latest stable version - only use the Beta version if desperate.

Take good backups first, and if the BIOS update encounters a problem, don't try
to force the flash.

Comment: I will try flashing the BIOS next. I also have jumper caps coming in tomorrow that I will use to reset the CMOS without a screwdriver. Thank you for the advice!

Comment: I looked at flashing the latest version of the BIOS, but I won't be able to do that if I can't see the bios in the first place?

Comment: This is usually done after boot, from Windows.

Comment: Ah gotcha, my bad.  I haven't flashed my BIOS before and the method I found online was M-Flash from the BIOS

Comment: Would you happen to know how I can flash my BIOS from windows? I can't find a method on it that doesn't take me to the UEFI settings

Comment: It seems like AMI BIOS is problematic. The best way might be to follow blindly [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LRyFMf0D9Lc) that tells the sequence of required key presses. There are apparently utilities [here](https://ami.com/en/products/firmware-tools-and-utilities/bios-uefi-utilities/) which could help, but they are really for developers and the documentation is terrible.